# How to check for null in the operator== method?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Consider the following class:

```
public class Code : IEquatable<Code> 
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
         return Equals(obj as Code);
    }

    public override bool Equals(Code code)
    {
         if (code == null) return false;
         return this.Value == code.Value;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Code a, Code b)
    {
         if (a == null) return b == null;
         return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Code a, Code b)
    {
         if (a == null) return b!= null;
         return !a.Equals(b);
    }

    // rest of the class here
}
```

Now try using the `==` method:

```
Code a = new Code();
Code b = new Code();
Console.WriteLine("The same? {0}", a==b);
```

The result is a `StackOverflowException` because the `==` method calls itself when it checks for null.

But if I take out the null check:

```
public static bool operator ==(Code a, Code b)
{
    return a.Equals(b);
}
```

I get a `NullReferenceException`!

What's the correct way to define these methods?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can also use `(object)a == null`

Comment: There is an alternative to this solution that currently has more upvotes, so let me note that `(object)a == null` results in faster code, to the extent that a `ReferenceEquals` op== implementation took more than twice as long as the equivalent using `(object)a == null`. If you use the same code also for `Equals`, this can have a knock-on effect in every `Distinct()`, `Dictionary<>`, `HashSet<>`, `ToLookup` etc. you use with this type as the key.

Comment: A Linqpad microbenchmark for those interested in replicating the perf problem with `ReferenceEquals`: https://github.com/EamonNerbonne/ValueUtils/blob/master/NullCheckBenchmark.linq.  Note that apparently sometimes the CLR does inline it, so if you're lucky it won't matter.

Answer (score 22):

use [`System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, null)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx)

Comment: The accepted solution `(object)a == null` is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in C# 7, you can simply use the `is` keyword to do a direct reference comparison. See [Thorkil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50811687/1168116) to [What is the difference between “x is null” and “x == null”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40676426/1168116)